# How large is the Exploding Palm AoE?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

This is the description of Exploding Palm:

> Cause a target to Bleed for 220% weapon damage as Physical over 3
>   seconds. If the target dies while bleeding, it explodes and deals 30%
>   of the target's maximum Life as Physical damage to all nearby enemies.

So it is clear to me that the more life the enemy has, more damage the explosion causes. But how big is the radius of explosion? Is it fixed?

I am trying to understand if a big monster (like the trees or beasts) causes a larger area of effect (AoE). Do you have any idea if size and radius are connected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the graphics and my experience, the radius is around 10 yards. I've been Exploding-Palming trees left and right and I didn't feel it to have a bigger range, and the graphics also do not appear different.

Have not used science to measure it, though.